# Best way to redirect user upon form submit to URL using input as directory

Tags: php, forms, redirect

Hello! I am trying to put together a landing page that will allow individuals to visit, enter an access code, and be redirected to a directory that corresponds to the access code. For example, access code is 12345, user is redirected to example.com/12345 upon submit. We will be using direct links for the most part, but in the event that someone hits a 404  or try to visit the root directory, we want to have an interface for returning to the project / an alternative way for people to access the page.

What might be the best way to redirect a user after they enter the access code in the form?

Thanks for your advice!

Comment: You can use a `javascript` redirect or a `PHP` redirect. It is truly up to you how you'd want to do this considering you know your application better than we do.

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to say what the 'best' solution would be as it's open to interpretation. Here's what I would do.

Instead of routing to a specific page, I would route them to a controller that includes the code and/or content from the user directory. This will allow you to secure any contents of the user directories through server configurations, and give you better programmatic control of what happens when something goes wrong.

The user key should be set to a session key but if you don't want to do that, you could set it to a POST or GET parameter just as easily.

```
if(array_key_exists("user",$_SESSION)){
    include_once("/".$_SESSION['user'].".php");
    //use the included file if it won't automatically run itself
}
else{
    echo "error - missing user key";
}
```